# Windows Explorer extension: how to handle opening links?

Tags: com, windows-explorer

I'm working on a specific document management system (DMS) which has, for design sake, a Tortoise-like Explorer extension. The simple part (custom context menu) is done, because there are a lot of resources, describing how to do it. (For instance, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens).

But I have faced a feature request to handle opening .lnk files (in Windows Explorer, of course) and process them (if needed) using the DMS instead of the standard verbs. I'm not sure whether it's possible at all using a COM callback interface (due to security reasons). I would avoid low-level techniques like hooks at all costs. Anyway it's supposed that our users work as admins, have all privileges etc.

Regards,